# error list index out of range related to label file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to learn a transfer learning (distinguishing cat and dog) myself.
And I don't get what is causing the indexing issue related to file labeling.
Below is my code.

```
IMG_DIM = (150, 150)
test_files = glob.glob('test_data/*')
test_imgs = [img_to_array(load_img(img, target_size=IMG_DIM)) for img in test_files]
test_imgs = np.array(test_imgs)
test_labels = [fn.split('/')[1].split('.')[0].strip() for fn in test_files]
test_imgs_scaled = test_imgs.astype('float32')
test_imgs_scaled /= 255
test_labels_enc = class2num_label_transformer(test_labels)
print('Test dataset shape:', test_imgs.shape)
print(test_labels[0:4], test_labels_enc[0:4])
```

And this is the error message.

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-166-d351a31bcadc> in <module>
      4 test_imgs = [img_to_array(load_img(img, target_size=IMG_DIM)) for img in test_files]
      5 test_imgs = np.array(test_imgs)
----> 6 test_labels = [fn.split('/')[1].split('.')[0].strip() for fn in test_files]
      7 
      8 test_imgs_scaled = test_imgs.astype('float32')

<ipython-input-166-d351a31bcadc> in <listcomp>(.0)
      4 test_imgs = [img_to_array(load_img(img, target_size=IMG_DIM)) for img in test_files]
      5 test_imgs = np.array(test_imgs)
----> 6 test_labels = [fn.split('/')[1].split('.')[0].strip() for fn in test_files]
      7 
      8 test_imgs_scaled = test_imgs.astype('float32')
```

IndexError: list index out of range

I also attach the folder which contains files used in this code.
[image: file used in this code]

Comment: `.split('/')[1]` must be the problem. One of your `fn` does not have any '/' in it.

Comment: This isn't anything to do with your machine learning. `fn.split('/')[1].split` assumes that every path has an `/` in it, which presumably is not true